# Yamaha F40F outboard boat engine continuous alarm when starting

Tags: engine, starting, yamaha, boat

I'm trying to start a very new 2014 Yamaha F40F engine on my dad's boat. The engine was used yesterday by my brother without issues but today it won't start at all, and I get a continuous alarm sound while the Engine Fault warning indicator is being shown in the display.

I made a very shaky video to demonstrate the startup procedure and the alarm: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l1kte7wha8

The engine was completely cold when I attempted to start it, and it worked fine yesterday. There are other warning indicators for such things as low oil pressure, low battery, water separator, and overheating. So I figure if any of those things was the problem here, those warning indicators would show instead of the more general "engine fault" indicator.

Any tips are very welcome.

Comment: is there gas in the boat?